# Return response before http-on-examine-response

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I am developing a Firefox addon, which needs to intercept the HTTP request process and return a fake response for certain URLs. This is the code I am using:

```
function TracingListener() {
    this.originalListener = null;
}

TracingListener.prototype = {
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        LOG("onDataAvailable");
        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, inputStream, offset, count);
    },

    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
        LOG("onStartRequest");
        this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);
    },


    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {
        LOG("onStopRequest");
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
        var stream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
        stream.setData("Test", -1);
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, Components.results.NS_OK);

    },

    QueryInterface: function (aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) ||
        aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
};

var observer = {
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
        LOG(topic);
        var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
        var url = httpChannel.URI.spec;
        LOG("Test:" + url);
        if (!pattern.test(url)) return;

        if (topic == 'http-on-modify-request') {
            var newListener = new TracingListener();
            newListener.originalListener = httpChannel.setNewListener(newListener);

            } else if (topic == "http-on-examine-response" || topic == "http-on-examine-cached-response" || topic == "http-on-examine-merged-response") {
            var newListener = new TracingListener();
            newListener.originalListener = httpChannel.setNewListener(newListener);
        }
    }
};


var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(observer, "http-on-modify-request", false);
observerService.addObserver(observer, "http-on-opening-request", false);
```

It works fine when there is a URL response: I can change the response to "Test".

But, for some URLs which cannot be reached or are really slow, `onStopRequest` is never called.

I need to return a request before any real request sent, which is "http-on-open-request" or "http-on-modify-request". But at that point, Firefox refuses to accept any response because he thinks (which is true) that the response should not available.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On `http-on-modify-request`, you should be able to call [redirectTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel#redirectTo()) or modify [nsIChannel.URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel) to send the request to a data URI like `data:text/plain,Test`.

Comment: Sorry for response late, great answer!